# How to show different message on specific width?

Tags: javascript

I have a progressbar in .js which displays a message when loading from 0 to 100%, this is the portion of code:

```
 $('#x00srch-status-current').html('Connecting...'); 
 $('#x00srch-progress').width('0%'); 
 $('#x00srch-progress').animate({
    width: '100%'
} )
```

How can I display different message on specific progressbar width? For example:

if `progress_width=20%`, then `status="Connecting..."`

`progress_width=50%`, then `status="Getting results..."`

`progress_width=82%`, then `status="The results will come up..."`

Comment: I don't know who down vote your question . However , could u put your DEMO here : http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `step` function to achieve what you need. It is a function that is called at each step (*weirdly*) of the animation:

Something like the following will do:

```
$('#x00srch-status-current').html('Connecting...');
$('#x00srch-progress').width('0%').animate({width:"100%"}, {
    duration:2000,
    step:function(n,fx){ 
        var status = "Connecting...";
        status = n >= 50 ? "Getting results..." : status;
        status = n >= 82 ? "The results will come up..." : status;
        $('#x00srch-status-current').html(status);
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fxvfJ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I have two Ideas for you:

1) jquery.animate has a default duration of 400 ms, and you are not defining any other, so you can set the Status with:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  status = "Connecting";
}, 80); //80ms are 20% of 400ms

setTimeout(function() {
  status = "Getting Results";
}, 200); //200ms are 50% of 400ms    

setTimeout(function() {
  status = "Getting Results";
}, 328); //328ms are 50% of 400ms
```

You can also store your animation duration in a variable, and calculate the percentages.

2) animate in Steps. First to 20%, change message, then to 50%, change message etc.
Use the animate Callback function.